# Encode string to HTML Asp.NET MVC razor

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVPTracker.Models.DashboardResult>
@using MVPTracker.Models;

@{
int row = 0;
ViewBag.Title = "DashboardList";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
string top =  "<div class='row'> ";
string Bot = "</div> ";
}

<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
                    @{
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            if (row == 0)
                            {
                                Html.Encode(top);     
                            }
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="ibox">
                                    <div class="ibox-content product-box">
                                        <div class="product-imitation">
                                            <img src="~/Images/App/EventHeader.jpg" width="100%" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-desc">
                                            <span class="product-price">
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sport.Name)
                                            </span>
                                            <a href="@Url.Action("ViewResults", "Results", new { key = Functions.encrypt(item.DashboardResultID.ToString()) })" class="product-name"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventName)</a>
                                            <div class="small m-t-xs">
                                                <strong>Desc:</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) <br />
                                                <strong>Date:</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
                                            </div>
                                            <br />
                                            <div class="m-t text-righ">
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("UploadResults", "Results", new { key = Functions.encrypt(item.DashboardResultID.ToString()) })" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary">Upload Results <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> </a>
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("ViewResults", "Results", new { key = Functions.encrypt(item.DashboardResultID.ToString()) })" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary">View Results <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            if (row == 3)
                            {
                                Html.Encode(Bot);
                                row = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row++;
                            }


                        }
                    }


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 variables that have a div snippet, I have to print the open div and close div when the row has full, with the actual code I cant make it, I try another stuff (HTMLString, HTML.Raw...) but nothing works, could you please give me a hand with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What have you tried  ? (This does not help " i try another stuff (HTMLString, HTML.Raw...) nut nothing works"))

Comment: At the top of the code i have this: string top =  "<div class='row'> "; and string Bot = "</div> "; I what to convert this into HTML and I tried with HTML.Raw(top) and HTML.Encode(Top) but nothing @Shyju

Comment: You want to print it as it is or you want to render that HTML into the page ?

Comment: I want to render that HTML into the page.

Comment: which .net version is this? .net core? or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name implies, the `Html.Encode` method will encode the input. If you are trying to render the HTML you have in the variable as the HTML for your page, You may use `Html.Raw` method.

[Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) method does not do html encoding. So make sure you are passing safe HTML to this page to prevent possible script injections.

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  if (row == 0)
  {
    @Html.Raw(top);     
  }
  <div>some html</div>
  if (row == 0)
  {
     @Html.Raw(Bot);
  }
  row++;
}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with HTML.Raw and doesnt work.. the snippet is not rendered.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was that I missed the "@" at the beggining of HTML.Raw

Answer (score 0):

I notice several problems with your code.

In

```
                        if (row == 0)
                        {
                            Html.Encode(top);     
                        }
```

you don't switch between C# and markup mode, so the result of (the wrong call to) `Html.Encode()` is lost.

Change this code to

```
                        if (row == 0)
                        {
                            <text>@Html.Raw(top)</text>
                        }
```

The same is true for the code beginning with `if (row == 3)`.

Next, you don't seem to close the opening `top` `<div>` after the `for` loop if the loop ends with a value of `row != 3`.

You should always check the rendered HTML with `View source code` or similar. I noticed Firefox indicates where unmatched tags have been "fixed", i.e. closing tags inserted etc. Probably other browser have similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can just omit both **DisplayFor** and **modelItem =>**,  so:

```
@Html.Raw(item.Description)
```